# How do hub icons change according to the theme in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm designing a hub extension for Azure DevOps and want to have an icon that follows the feel of the existing hub icon groups.

[image] [image]

What do I need to do to get my icon to behave like these others when themes (particularly light vs dark) are applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/web-navigation?view=azure-devops) (which doesn't even work), it's quite simple. In your extensions manifest specify the icons as follows:

```
{
    "id": "hub",
    "type": "ms.vss-web.hub",
    "targets": [
        "ms.vss-work-web.work-hub-group"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": "Hub",
        "description": "Something",
        "uri": "pages/Hub.html",
        "icon": {
            "light": "img/hub-light.png",
            "dark": "img/hub-dark.png"
        }
    }
}
```